# Win32 C++ WNetAddConnection2 with domain name?

Tags: c++, winapi, fileshare

I am working on a machine that will be in kiosk mode when placed at a customer site. The application GUI will be the only interface the user has to the system, and the application needs to map/unmap shared folders when a user wants to copy files to a remote location.  I am using WNetAddConnection2 to map, and once the user leaves the Copy dialog, I am using WNetCancelConnection2 to unmap.  According to the needs of the customer, this machine may be placed directly on the domain that owns the shared folders, or it may be placed on a separate domain.  For our tests, we have the machine on a domain that doesn't have DNS access, and the destination file share is on an Active Directory server on a separate domain.  Using WNetAddConnection2, I can give my username, password, and a path such as \\, but won't get a connection, path not found.  That's correct with no DNS on this domain.  I then tried \\, and I with that path I can get there just fine.

The question that I have is, neither the call to WNetAddConnection2 nor the NETRESOURCE struct has a field for passing the domain name.  Is it the case with WNetAddConnection2 that the username field in the NETRESOURCE struct can be of the form \?  I haven't seen any documentation to prove or disprove that that is the case.  I am wanting to make sure of this, because using the destination system's name instead of an IP address, it may be necessary to specify domain.  As you may have noticed from this question, this is not my main field of expertise.  I've been digging to find an answer, but haven't yet come up with anything definitive.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You use the same name you'd use in the NET USE command.  If that command doesn't work then you'll never get it working in your code either.  And with no name provider around at all, it of course isn't going to work.  Follow up at serverfault.com

Comment: Great, thanks.  I thought as much but didn't see anything backing my theory.  Just needed some verification.  This helps a lot.

Comment: Don't change your title to include "Solved". If there is an answer, mark it as accepted. If not, create an answer yourself how this was "solved", and then mark that as accepted.

Comment: I reverted your edit. Adding *[SOLVED]* to the title is not how things are done here. If you have a solution you'd like to share, add it as an actual answer just like anyone else would (in the *Your Answer* space below). If you'd like to withdraw the question, delete it (the link to do so is below the question's tags).

Answer (score 0):

[WNetAddConnection2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) accepts domain names in both the `lpRemoteName` field of the `NETRESOURCE` and the `lpUserName` parameter. Specify the remote name as `\\server\resource` or `\\IPAddress\resource`, and the user name in `domain\username` format.

(Of course, you'll need to properly escape the backslash characters in C/C++.)

Slightly modified example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
NETRESOURCE nr;
DWORD res;
TCHAR szUserName[32] = "MyDomain\\MyUserName",
    szPassword[32] = "MyPassword",
    szLocalName[32] = "Q:",
    szRemoteName[MAX_PATH] = "\\\\products2\\relsys";

nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
nr.lpLocalName = szLocalName;
nr.lpRemoteName = szRemoteName;
nr.lpProvider = NULL;

res = WNetAddConnection2(&nr, szPassword, szUserName, FALSE);

if(res == NO_ERROR)
  printf("Connection added \n", szRemoteName);
else
  printf("Error: %ld\n", res);
  return;
}
```