# How do I map a network drive on a domain in code

Tags: delphi, winapi, network-programming

I am using this function to map a network drive:

```
CONST
  MapNetDrvDefFlags     = CONNECT_TEMPORARY OR CONNECT_INTERACTIVE {$IFDEF CONSOLE } OR CONNECT_COMMANDLINE {$ENDIF };

FUNCTION MapNetworkDrive(D : CHAR ; CONST UNC,UserName,Password,Provider : STRING ; Flags : DWORD = MapNetDrvDefFlags) : DWORD;
  VAR
    NetResource : _NETRESOURCEW;
    LocalRes    : STRING;

  BEGIN
    FillChar(NetResource,SizeOf(_NETRESOURCEW),0);
    NetResource.dwType:=RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
    LocalRes:=D+':'; NetResource.lpLocalName:=POINTER(LocalRes);
    NetResource.lpRemoteName:=POINTER(UNC);
    NetResource.lpProvider:=POINTER(Provider);
    Result:=WNetAddConnection2W(NetResource,POINTER(Password),POINTER(UserName),Flags)
  END;
```

and it works fine on a standard SAMBA WORKGROUP network. But at a customer's place it doesn't. It **does** map the drive, but when I try to access it, I get an "invalid user or password" error.

One difference I notice is that if I execute a manual

```
NET USE <Drive>: <UNC>
```

on my own network (WORKGROUP), I get a simple prompt for a user name. But on the customer's network, I get a different prompt:

```
Skriv brugernavnet for 'xxxx.yyyy':
```

(translation: Enter user name for 'xxxx.yyyy')

I assume that this is a domain name, but how do I give that to the WNetAddConnection2W call? I have tried sending username as "xxxx.yyyy@user" but that doesn't work. Is there another place I need to supply a domain name (if this is, indeed, what it is)?

I have also tried specifying the xxxx.yyyy part as the "Provider" in the _NETRESOURCEW structure, but if I do that, I get an "Invalid provider" error.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/29420529/759049 ?

Comment: @Pateman Ahh - "\" as seperator, not "@". I'll try this out and if it works, you can make it into an answer and I'll accept it.. It may be an hour or so for me to check it out...

Comment: @Pateman: That worked. If you make it an answer (and flesh it out a bit), I'll accept it...

Comment: `domain\account` is the historical syntax and expected for decades already in most functions, while the syntax `account@domain` is more en vogue these days. See [Any difference between DOMAIN\username and username@domain.local?](https://serverfault.com/q/371150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer to a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29420529/759049

In essence, I think that you should just use domain name in `lpRemoteName` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I actually did it in the lpUserName, and it worked fine...